# Extract Data from Web Page including HYPERLINKS in it - using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have extracted all the required data from a web page. Now the issue is that if the page contains any hyperlink then i have to extract the data with that hyperlinks also.I have attached the code for which the data is extracted.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://sienna/VBGSIWeb/Production/ItemStatus.aspx?item=" & PN, _
        Destination:=Range("$N$1"))
        .Name = "ItemStatus.aspx?item=BC-00003"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = """gvSAPRevHistory"""
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

`

I have also attached the snapshot of the webquerytable.

[image]

In this I have to copy and paste the CN# to desired cell including hyperlink.

Comment: that is an unreachable URL

Comment: It can't be reached as it is private web of a organization @jsotola

Answer (score 0):

Can you just turn on the Macro recorder and click through the steps you need to perform?  I think that's your best bet.  This doesn't seem to be a URL that any Tom, Dick, and harry can access.  Good luck.